# Can't find function iconv_strpos after server migration

Tags: magento-1.9, zend-framework, format, php-5.5

I just changed my magento 1.9 installation to a dedicated server. I uploaded the file system and the database to the new server.

When I try to access my website, the following line appears in my error_log:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function iconv_strpos() in /lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 827
```

And the only thing my page shows is the home button of my website.

Did I have something more to do about my migration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here, how did you solved this issue ? However in my case the only problem is GoogleFeed generator but still ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means `iconv` PHP extension is off.

Did you setup your server yourself? Contact hosting and tell them to install `iconv` for you.

Comment: This answer is not an answer. :(